# Design Question: edit in place form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, inline-editing

I have a Rails app with an index page listing products and I'd like to be able to update multiple fields from the index page.
Just like in basecamp or wordpress, you mouse over a line, it shows a list of links to many actions you can do on the item, all in ajax.
I'm thinking about combining jquery for effects and the edit in place plugin.
Is this a good design or would yo proceed differently?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good. Anything that makes it easier for your customer to use the site is welcome.  And to prevent them jumping around in multiple screens to perform simple updates is even better.